# Why not stop the program when they break point?

Tags: actionscript-3, breakpoints, flashdevelop

I did a project in AS3 and I used this code:

```
   public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main() 
        {

            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            var numar:Number = 10; //here I put the breakpoint
            var rectangle:Shape = new Shape; // initializing the variable named rectangle
            rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); // choosing the colour for the fill, here it is red
            rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100,100); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
            rectangle.graphics.endFill(); // not always needed but I like to put it in to end the fill
            addChild(rectangle); // adds the rectangle to the stage
        }

    }

}
```

This app is just one test.
For example I want to stop the program when the variable is created and see its value.

If you press F5 to run the program continue and not stop at the breakpoint.

I use development environment Flash Develop.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thaks in advance!

Comment: Check if compile mode is "debug", if not, breakpoints are not in effect.

Comment: How can I put it in debug mode?

Comment: There's a pulldown list at the upper right of FD's main window, there's "Debug" and "Release" - set "Debug" and try again.

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/2vv2ezt.jpg   here you mean?

Comment: ... I found it in debug but still does not stop